# vuejs method not working inside bootstrap modal event

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have bootstrap (4.3) modal in vuejs app. On modal show I want to send gtag (google analytics) data. I have tried

```
async created() {
//some other code
 $('#modalRecommend').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    this.gtagFunction('pressed', 'my cat','test label','no');
    $('body').addClass('modal-recommend-open');
  }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('body').removeClass('modal-recommend-open');
  });
 }
```

When modal show it is showing error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.gtagFunction is not a function

If I place `this.gtagFunction()` this outside `$('#modalRecommend').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {..` then it is works.

Note: I have loaded a mixins in parent component where `this.gtagFunction()` is available. Also I have tried to add `@click.native` in HTML like

```
<img @click.native="sendAnalytics()" class="w-auto mr-2" src="/pic.png" width="120" height="40" v show="recommendRankingWorks.length > 0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRecommend" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
```

with

```
methods{
sendAnalytics: function(){
            this.gtagFunction('pressed', 'my cat','test label','no');
        },
}
```

but not fired. Only show modal

Comment: u can replace function to arrow function. E.g. function() {} to () => {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you called

```
$('#modalRecommend').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    this.gtagFunction('pressed', 'my cat','test label','no');
```

`this` is not bounded to Vue instance, but to the jQuery object `$('#modalRecommend')`. That's why you cannot access `gtagFunction` defined in your Vue component.

Since you can call the function outside of jQuery call, you can try to call `gtagFunction` like this:

```
const { gtagFunction } = this;
$('#modalRecommend').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    gtagFunction('pressed', 'my cat','test label','no');
```

Comment: I have just use `let self = this;self.gtagFunction('pressed', 'my cat','test label','no');` and now working. Perhaps your solution will also will work. I have got the idea from your answer. Thanks